How to smoothen normals in geo nodes without smoothing the geometry?
I'm trying to get a simpler shape so that certain effects (e.g reflections, transmissions, caustics) are easier to compute with low samples.
My idea has been to smooth the geometry with geo nodes and get the modified normals to test how it works when rendered. And it looks promising but I'm stuck.
I can't get the normal attribute of an unconnected branch in geo nodes to be exported.
And I don't want to apply the shape modification either.
Any help on how to smoothen normals either in geo nodes or in the shader appreciated.


Actually, the value has to be transferred back to each vertex of the original geometry using a Sample index.
Learn something every day :)

